# Having troubles getting all columns in an SQL Join - BigQuery SQL JOINS

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I am having some troubles with SQL Joins in Bigquery. I am very new to SQL, so I am pretty sure it's just some fundamental understanding type issue. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Sample Join:

```
SELECT domain,content1,content2,content3,content4 FROM `project.dataset.content` //10 rows
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(Select domain from `project.dataset.all_domains`) USING (domain) //100 rows - This is a single column list of all GUIDs in my dataset. Each Table uses the same GUIDs a portion of this list, so I am joining it to ensure I get all data returned to a single table
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(Select * [e.g.: domain,color1,color2,etc.] from`project.dataflowed.color`)  USING (domain) // 10 rows
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(Select * from `project.dataset.language`) USING (domain) //10 rows
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(Select * from `project.dataset.type`) USING (domain) //10 rows
```

I thought I understood how this worked, but I seem to be getting just:

|| domain | content1 | content2 | content3 | content4 ||
<--100 rows-->

But I am hoping to get:
|| domain | content1 | content2 | content3 | content4 | color 1 | color 2... | language2 | language 2... | type1 | type2...||
<--100 rows-->

So am essentially not getting the columns from any but the original (left?) table..?

Can someone help me understand what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: please provide more meaningful example! it is totally not clear to me what your problem is  - you have `SELECT 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and that is exactly what you are getting! i don't see how one could expect anything else. so, just explain what you are trying to achieve with more presentable example

Comment: Edited now to add more details, hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So am essentially not getting the columns from any but the original (left?) table..?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and addresses specifically above question - I assume your `FULL OUTER JOIN` part is correct and represent whatever logic you expect

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.content` 
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.all_domains` USING(domain)
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.color` USING(domain)
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.language` USING(domain)
FULL OUTER JOIN `project.dataset.type` USING(domain)
```

Above assumes that the only common field name between all tables is `domain` - otherwise you need to enlist all the output fields explicitly in SELECT list and provide aliases for ambiguous fields. Like `SELECT domain, content1, content2, color1, color2, ...`

Comment: Oops: on a side note, any tips on a better place to ask really basic questions like this? I get the impression that this question is too novice for stack overflow. Is there a better place to ask questions for beginners that you can recommend?

Comment: it is more about quality of the question rather than about you being beginner or expert. not only question needs to be asked that it is clear and understood - you should also show your efforts along with reproducible example with input and output data, etc. so definitely SO is the place for all developers including beginners